# error: Cannot update time stamp of directory 'docplex.egg-info'

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I've been trying to install cplex in my device
After downloading the cplex program and install it on my device
i want to install the python cplex
but i faced this error in cmd

```
error: Cannot update time stamp of directory 'docplex.egg-info'
Could not install docplex, code = 1
```

how can i fix this error
and install python cplex correctly